# MySql Table Insert if not exist otherwise update on non-unique columns

Tags: php, mysql

In a table like this:

```
ID | user_ID | name     | value
1  | 36      | order    | {1, 'asc'}
2  | 36      | colvis   | 0,1,2,4,7
3  | 36      | colorder | 0,1,2,4,3,5,6,7
4  | 37      | colvis   | 0,1,2,4,5,7
```

where only ID is unique and AUTO_INCREMENT, I need to INSERT new row for user_ID=36 and colvis='something', if row 'colvis' for that user doesn't exist already, i.e do something like 'INSERT IF NOT EXIST user_ID=x AND name=y ELSE UPDATE' query.

For example, if I have user_ID=36 and name='colorder', it should update row 3, but with user_ID=37 and name='colorder' it should insert new row. Same with user_ID=36 and name='filter', it should insert a new row.

It can be done with

```
$exist = $sql->Query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE user_ID = 36 AND name='colvis'");
if ($exist) {
  //UPDATE
} else {
  // INSERT
}
```

But isn't there a one-liner?

I looked at [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists?rq=1) and  [MySQL procedure to create or update a row in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520361/mysql-procedure-to-create-or-update-a-row-in-a-table) and [MySql Insert if not exist two column pair otherwise update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626782/mysql-insert-if-not-exist-two-column-pair-otherwise-update), but those are not applicable unless I have 'user_ID' and 'name' columns unique, are they?

Comment: See INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY - and read up on normalisation too

Comment: check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @Strawberry am I mistaken that INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY works only if I have unique values in columns? What do You mean by normalisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.  But first, you need a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_test_userID_name on test(user_ID, name)
```

Then you can do an insert:

```
insert into test(user_ID, name, value)
    values (36, 'colvis', '3')
    on duplicate key update value values(val);
```

A big caveat here:  Storing multiple values in a comma-delimited list is almost never the right thing to do.  There are rare exceptions to this rule, which is why I've answered the question.

The right solution is probably a junction table, `TestValues`, with one row per "test" and one row per "value".  In that case, what you want to do is easy:

```
insert into TestValues(test_id, value)
    values (test_id, val);
```

Comment: If I try to add unique index to user_ID, phpMyAdmin gives an error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '36' for key 'user_ID'".
As for storing comma-delimeted list: it's for storing DataTable preferences after logout, which are mostly arrays.

Comment: @Konservin . . . The unique index has two keys, not one.  Look at the example in the answer.

Comment: My bad.
Still: 
    insert into test(user_ID, name, val)
    values (36, 'colvis', '3')
    on duplicate key update set val = concat(val, ',', values(val));
gives error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set val = concat(val, ',', values(val))' at line 3"
    INSERT INTO AK_user_vars (user_ID, name, value) VALUES(36, 'colvis', '3,5,6,7,9') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
    user_ID=36, name='colvis', value='3,5,6,7,10';
doesn't give error but no update either.

Comment: @Konservin . . . My bad.  There is no `set` in the statement.  I just think there *should* be.

Comment: Perfect, thank You: 

    insert into test(user_ID, name, value)
    values (36, 'colvis', '3,5,6,7,9')
    on duplicate key update value = '3,5,6,7,13'; worked as a charm (row updated), and insert into test(user_ID, name, value)
    values (39, 'colvis', '3,5,6,7,9')
    on duplicate key update value = '3,5,6,7,9'; worked too (row inserted). Problem solved. Just one small question: for some reason, when a row was updated, phpMySql said "2 rows inserted" not "1 row updated". Why is that?

Comment: @Konservin . . . Perhaps you have a trigger on the table.

Comment: 'There are no triggers to display' says phpMyAdmin. It's really not relevant at all to the question, I'm just curious.